# How to generate a tooltip showing the Information of selected symbol?

Tags: front-end, tooltip

Other editors/IDEs often provide the tooltip functionality that when hovering over a variable, the information will be popped up.
For example, in VSCode.

[image]

**Is it possible to simulate this in Mathematica frontend?**

---

I tried the `Tooltip` function with `NotebookApply` like the following, but this will overwrite the original expression.

```
NotebookApply[
    InputNotebook[],
    RowBox[{"Tooltip[#,Information[#]]&","[","\[SelectionPlaceholder]","]"}],
    All
];
SelectionEvaluate[InputNotebook[]];
```

---

Another try by `CreateDialog`

```
MenuItem["Show Information of Selected Symbol",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
        If[
            NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]]==={},
            FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ExpandSelection"]];
        ];
        If[
            Head[NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]]]===Cell,
            Null,
            CreateDialog[Information[NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]]],WindowFloating->True]
        ]
    ],
    MenuKey[";", Modifiers -> {"Command"}],
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"
]
```

This will pop up a dialog window like

[image]

but is still far from the convenient tooltip functionality, since I need to use shortcut to generate and close this dialog window.

Comment: When you hover over a symbol, a blue raft appears with two buttons (⮟ and i), and the information appears when you click on ⮟. So if I understand correctly, you just want to eliminate this click on ⮟ so that the information would appear immediately upon hovering?

Comment: @Domen ⮟ is not exactly the `Information` and I don't know how to customize it. In lots of situations `Attributes` and `Options` are what I need. So the question is about how to generate the tooltip programmatically.

Comment: There is [`ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InformationPopup/), which is quite similar to what you tried, just in a pre-packaged form and with a cleaner popup. It still requires a shortcut though, but I don't think you can avoid that unfortunately.

Comment: @LukasLang Thx!

Comment: `ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]` is nice. BTW, in the code provided by the question description, you should use `TemplateBox` or `InterpretationBox`.